# Meteor: No context for #each loop event handlers

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I'm using an #each loop with an unmanaged local collection to generate a sequence of input fields for a form.  However, when I try to use `this._id` in the event handler it is undefined.  In fact, the context being passed to the event handler is for the window.  Any help to find what is going wrong and how I should be getting the proper context as `this` within my event handler is much appreciated.

The code is:

```
<h4 class="page-header">Children on this account</h4> 
{{#each children}}
<div id={{_id}} class="form-group col-md-12 child-form-instance">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" name="childFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Child's First Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-5 col-xs-10">
        <input type="text" name="childLastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Child's Last Name" value="{{_id}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-child" aria-label="remove child">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="button" id="addChild" class="btn btn-success" value="Add child">
</div>
```

and the js:

```
var children = new Mongo.Collection(null);

Template.signup.onRendered( () => {
  Modules.client.signupValidateSubmit({
    form: "#signup",
    template: Template.instance()
  });
    children.remove({});
    children.insert({});  //create one empty child

});

Template.signup.events({
    'submit form': ( event ) => event.preventDefault(),
    'click #addChild': () => {
        children.insert({});
        console.log(children.find().fetch());
    },
    'click .remove-child': () => {
        console.log(this);
    }
});

Template.signup.helpers({
    children () {
        return children.find();    
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine with the addChild button, and the `_id`s are getting properly assigned in the DOM, but the remove-child class is logging the `window` context.

Comment: Well, you are using arrow functions which will lexically bind `this`. As a result, you get the _wrong_ context.

Comment: Yes, that was the whole problem.  `function()` fixes it.  It appears I should read up on ES2015 a bit more rather than just parroting a few of the conventions I see.  Thanks for the help Matthias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will lexically bind `this` with the parent scope. As a consequence, you don't get the scope of `children`.

In order to solve the issue, just change the template event to:

```
Template.signup.events({
    // ...
    'click .remove-child': function (event, template) {
        console.log(this);
    }
    // ...
});
```